# DrawRect not called from main view

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsview, drawrect

I am writing a MacOS application and my main view is in the main AppDelegate file, defined in the IB.
How can I have a DrawRect called when I resize the main window ?
All examples I read are based on an additional view started with initWithFrame, which is not the case for the main view.
Thanks.

Comment: I tried to add this drawRect in my code, but it is never called. I even added a [self.superview setNeedsDisplay:YES], but it didn't help.

Comment: In you AppDelegate file write subclass of NSView. Then whenever you resize your window DrawRect will called automatically